# I want someway to know that my python script is running before it shows any results

Tags: python, machine-learning, jupyter-notebook

I'm using python on jupyter notebook to learn machine learning.

A lot of times, when I run the code, it will take eternity to show any results. As a result, a lot of times I wonder whether my script is properly running or whether it crashed.

Jupyter Notebook shows whether a Kernel is idle or busy. However, thats not enough! I want to know whether if I wait for like 5 minutes, I would get the results.

I know that for loops, I could make it print something evertime an iteration is done. but for Matrix multiplications.... I don't know what to do since the process is just one multiplication in code.

Is there a code that shows how my code is running(elapsed time, current stage)?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/tqdm/tqdm is a nice, low overhead, progress bar

Comment: Wow Thanks for your wonderful advice. However, I see that tqdm works for loops. Is there something like tqdm that works for some function like np.dot(X,Y)? These things sometimes takes some time

Comment: Either the function would have to do something to show its progress (numpy functions don't, as far as I know), or you'd have to do something hacky to trace it, which would probably make it take even longer.

Comment: thanks for your answer. I guess sometimes you just need to have a little faith

Comment: @HongJoonKim There is a `pandas` wrapper, so either you can maybe switch to `pandas`, or you can try to make your own wrapper for `numpy` (if `numpy` provides a way to include your own logic like `pandas` does...).